# Trouble with markers in Google API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Despite lots of research, I am having trouble with markers in Google API v3.

As far as I can see, all is correct.

Any idea why this won't work?
http://www.lostkettle.com/lettings/testing_maps.php

Comment: Does [this page](http://lostkettle.com/lettings/testing_maps.php) (note: no www) work?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `http://lostkettle.com/lettings/querymap.php` with `/lettings/querymap.php` in `downloadUrl` call .

The problem is for [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).